# How can I determine the precise exception when a connection to SQL Server fails (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a (Windows Forms) app that will be installed on various users' desktops; it will allow them to generate reports based on custom code that connects to a SQL Server Database and reads records from certain tables.

The Connection String is:

```
Data Source=PLATYPUS;Initial Catalog=Duckbills;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=lilabner;Password=d0GpAtCh42;Connect Timeout=120
```

I understand this to mean that if all the following is true:

```
The user's machine has the SQL Server client software installed
The SQL Server client has been configured to access the PLATYPUS database
The table "Duckbills" exists in that database
The username and password are what is expected
```

...then the connection will be successful.

In the event any of the above equate to false, I want to show the user a "user-friendly" message informing them, in plain English, what the problem is and what to do about it. How can I test for these various problems so that the most appropriate message is shown the user in the event of connection failure.

Here is the pertinent existing code:

```
DataSet dsUsage = new DataSet();
SqlConnection conn =
    new SqlConnection("SERVER=PLATYPUS;DATABASE=Duckbills;UID=lilabner;PWD=d0GpAtCh42;Connection Timeout=0");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Exec sp_ViewPlatypi";
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
conn.Open();
da.Fill(dsUsage);
conn.Close();

DataTable dtUsage = dsUsage.Tables[0];
if (dtUsage.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow productUsageByMonthDataRow in dtUsage.Rows)
    {
        . . .

catch (Exception ex)
{
    String exDetail = String.Format(PlatypusConstsAndUtils.ExceptionFormatString, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
    MessageBox.Show(exDetail);
}
```

As you can see, I have a "catch all" (no pun intended) Catch block. I want something like:

```
catch (SQLServerException sex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("SQL Server not available - go tell the DBA");
}
catch (NoTableException ntex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Go tell the DBA there's no such table");
}
catch (BadPwdException sex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your username and/or password are bad - go tell it to the Marines");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    String exDetail = String.Format(PlatypusConstsAndUtils.ExceptionFormatString, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
    MessageBox.Show(exDetail);
}
```

...but I don't know, first if all, if it's even possible to get that granular with connection exception messages, and secondly - if it is - just what the corresponding Exception types are.

Comment: `Data Source` is the address to the database server. `Initial catalog` is the name of the database. You don't connect to a specific table.

Comment: Catch on the `SqlException` also with a reputation as high as yours one would think that you would know how to ask / format a question.. why are you posting partial code.. come on now

Comment: I elided the unnecessary.

Comment: Catch the SqlException and then checkout the .Number property. Number codes are here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MethodMan I agree with B. Clay Shannon. There was enough information to determine what was being asked.

Comment: You would have to write your own code for this. Probably the easiest it to evaluate the ErrorMessage or ErroNumber inside the catch for SQLServerException. To truly this the way you have coded you would to write your own custom error classes and then throw the appropriate one based on the the error message.

Comment: @TheShaman your comment is useless in this context I can clearly see what he was trying to ask..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip your code back to handle Exception (catch (Exception ex)). Then, put a break point in your catch block. Attach the debugger to your code and when it hits the catch block, drag the ex variable in to your watch window. There, you will see all the details of the exception and you can determine what you need to be able to better handle the various exceptions that come up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on MethodMan's suggestion and TheShaman's link, I adapted that code to this:

```
catch (SqlException sex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sex.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        String sexDetail = String.Format("SQL Exception #{0}{1}Source: {2}{1}Number: {3}{1}State: {4}{1}Class: {5}{1}Server: {6}{1}Message: {7}{1}Procedure: {8}{1}LineNumber: {9}",
            i+1, // Users would get the fantods if they saw #0 
            Environment.NewLine, 
            sex.Errors[i].Source, 
            sex.Errors[i].Number, 
            sex.Errors[i].State, 
            sex.Errors[i].Class, 
            sex.Errors[i].Server, 
            sex.Errors[i].Message, 
            sex.Errors[i].Procedure, 
            sex.Errors[i].LineNumber);
        MessageBox.Show(sexDetail);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    String exDetail = String.Format(UsageRptConstsAndUtils.ExceptionFormatString, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace);
    MessageBox.Show(exDetail);
}
```

And for an example of what this produces:

[image]

Comment: LOL might be worth considering changing the variable name for your SqlException. :D

Comment: maybe simply x? I don't know about you but I am not keen on sex errors.